# Waiting for completion of several DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing, synchronization

Product design use separate tables with similar signatures for holding different kind of data.

As so you can perform calculation on each table separately in parallel without locks.

I optimize calculation code so it run it 7 times faster, but next 10% of performance boosting I think require x10 more time for coding/testing.

Calculation must be performed on all tables so it is logically to make calculation in parallel (especially when server have 32 cores). For such purpose I found useful [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) package:

```
declare
  job1 clob := dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name('REPAYMENT_');
  job2 clob := dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name('REPAYMENT_');
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => job1,
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'begin calc_rep(30, DATE ''2012-01-01'', DATE ''2012-12-31''); end;',
    enabled => true,
    auto_drop => true);
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => job2,
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'begin calc_rep(31, DATE ''2012-01-01'', DATE ''2012-12-31''); end;',
    enabled => true,
    auto_drop => true);
  dbms_output.put_line('jobs was finished');
end;
/
```

But I don't know how to wait for jobs finishing before *jobs was finished* message...

Constantly polling **scheduler_jobs** in loop is an inefficient solution but it is only one that come in mind. Search and official docs take no any relevant solution.

Comment: creating a job doesn't launch it.  Sounds like you want a JOB CHAIN, where you can run many steps (jobs) in a specific order (or concurrently).  I'm too busy atm to give a bunch of code, but see [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-enhancements-10gr2.php#job_chains) for an example

Answer (score 1):

Jobs are not used for parallelism (at least that's not what they're *for*). Jobs are used to invoke a procedure at a particular time and on a particular schedule. So you don't start a job and wait for it to finish.

Anyway, what you've done is create the job but never invoke them to start running. You'd have to call `dbms_scheduler.run_job( job_name => job1 )` to do that. That call would return immediately and your long-running job would continue to run in the background.

If I understand your question correctly, what you're trying to do is break up some complicated calculation and run it in parallel, but not necessarily run it repeatedly on a schedule. What you want is [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_parallel_ex.htm), where you break a large job up into chunks based on some criteria and run those individually.